# How to get rid of the error: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject

Tags: java, json

Getting the error, JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject, while getting an object from the JSON array (Java code line #5).

jQuery on client side

```
function setCosting(){
        var costingArray = {};
        costingArray = getCostingArray();
        var costingData = JSON.stringify(costingArray);
        alert(costingData);
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/costApp/budgetline.do?action=setCosting",
            data:{"costingData": costingData},
            datatype:'json',
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg) {
                    alert('success');
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert('error');
            }

        });
    function getCostingArray() {
        var rows = $("table tbody tr");
        var dataset = [];
        rows.each(function(i, row){
            var rowset = {};
            var $row = $(row);
            rowset['travelType'] = $row.find('#travelType').val();
            rowset['staff'] = $row.find('#staff').val();
            rowset['trip'] = $row.find('#trip').val();
            dataset.push(rowset);
        });

        return dataset;
    }

    $('#save').click(function() {
        setCosting();
    });
```

Java Code

```
Map mpVal = request.getParameterMap();    
JSONObject rootObj = new JSONObject(mpVal);
        JSONArray arrayObj = rootObj.getJSONArray("costingData");
        for(int m=0; m<arrayObj.length(); m++){
            **JSONObject costing = arrayObj.getJSONObject(m);**
            System.out.println(costing.getInt("travelType"));
            System.out.println(costing.getInt("staff"));
            System.out.println(costing.getInt("trip"));
        }
```

The array contains a sigle element with the value:

```
[
    {
        "travelType": "1",
        "staff": "red",
        "trip": ""
    },
    {
        "travelType": "2",
        "staff": "blue",
        "trip": ""
    },
    {
        "travelType": "3",
        "staff": "green",
        "trip": ""
    }
]
```

Any comment would be appreciated.

Comment: can you check if this is true `arrayObj.get(m) instanceof JSONObject`

Comment: also can you please add how `mpVal` JSON looks like, i am assuming that the JSON you have shown is `arrayObj` JSONArray

Comment: Checked. arrayObj is the instance of JSONObject

Comment: The array contains 3 elements!  Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax -- it only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.

Comment: Print out the original JSON string, before you've done anything to it.

Comment: Any reason why you continue to refuse to post the original JSON?

Comment: I am new to JSON. What do you mean original JSON string? I already posted the string that I got during debug here, see the 3rd part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Since, the array contains a single element with a value that's an array itself, you need

```
JSONArray arrayObj = rootObj.getJSONArray("costingData").getJSONArray(0);
for(int m=0; m<arrayObj.length(); m++){
    JSONObject costing = arrayObj.getJSONObject(m);
    System.out.println(costing.getString("travelType"));
    System.out.println(costing.getString("staff"));
    System.out.println(costing.getString("trip"));
}
```

And, since `staff` and `trip` are strings you need to use `getString()` instead of `getInt()`.

Comment: Now, I am getting the same error at line #3 after appending getJSONArray(0)

Comment: @SERICONBANG Please, share the full JSON. The structure isn't clear enough.

Comment: Thanks. Posted the full JSON